# Angular dependencies not being included from local files

Tags: html, angularjs

I have the following lines on my **index.html** file to include various dependencies

```
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

However, It keep getting the following error.  [image]

It seems like it is trying to retrieve angular and other dependencies from localhost.

How do I resolve this error?

Comment: check the path of files which you defined in index.html with reference to path of your index.html page @paris_serviola

Comment: Please provide your index.html , server and directory structure, for more clarity on the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check your server's base filepath, its should be set to a directory level just above bower_components/

> Example : if your directory structure is app/bower_components/xx/xx.js, set your server's static serve path to app/

Assuming that you are using node and express as your server, use [this](http://www.fullstacktraining.com/articles/how-to-serve-static-files-with-express) link for knowledge on setting static paths.

I don't see any other problem with this. As the error is **404** which means your files are not being located by the server.

Answer (score 0):

check if file are already in the real path, if not, install them with: bower install